# BLS API in R only returns 31

Tags: r, api

I'm starting to using the API of BLS to retrieve some unemployment data in R. However, as I am unexperienced with the API I am unable to retrieve more than a list of 31 (from July 2014 to January 2012) while there is data from 1978 (although I read here: http://www.datascienceriot.com/?p=53 that only a max of 10 years is possible, even this I can't seem to get).

Can somebody help me out? Included the code below. Thanks in advance.

Robert

code

```
bls.content <- getURLContent("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/LASST010000000000003")
bls.json <- fromJSON(bls.content, simplify=TRUE)
tmp <-bls.json$Results[[1]][[1]]
bls.df <- data.frame(year=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","year"),
                 period=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","period"),
                 periodName=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","periodName"),
                 value=as.numeric(sapply(tmp$data,"[[","value")), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

(this is not a working answer but it should get you on the right track or possibly have someone else tell what is wrong with the `httr` `POST` call)

using the `httr` library, you should be able to translate: this curl command-line:

```
curl -v -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{ "seriesid":["LASST010000000000003"], "startyear":"2004", "endyear":"2014" }' \
     http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/
```

(which comes from [this doc](http://www.bls.gov/developers/api_unix.htm))

into:

```
POST("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/", 
      content_type_json(),
      body=sprintf('{ "seriesid":"%s", "startyear":"%s", "endyear":"%s" }', "LEU0254555900", 2005, 2012),
      verbose())
```

Unlike the command-line (which gets all the data), the `httr` `POST` gives:

```
-> POST /publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/ HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0 Rcurl/1.95.4.3 httr/0.5
-> Host: api.bls.gov
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip
-> Cookie: JSESSIONID=FD2EAE55DE9288D89B54B00030E8B68C.tc_instance8
-> accept: application/json, text/xml, */*
-> Content-Length: 68
-> 
>> { "seriesid":"LEU0254555900", "startyear":"2005", "endyear":"2012" }

<- HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
<- Date: Mon, 08 Sep 2014 15:48:27 GMT
<- Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
<- Content-Length: 1047
```

But, they should be almost equivalent (I've played with various `accept()` header changes as well).

The list form of the `body=` in the `POST` doesn't work since the JSON won't be in the format the BLS API expects (AFAICanTell).